# Two step probability draw - Combine probability weighting function and a draw from a truncuated normal distribution

Tags: python, random, probability, normal-distribution, random-seed

I want to draw a random value (r) with python according to a specific probability function:

The value should be a fixed constant with a probability (p) and with a probability (1-p) the value is randomly drawn from a normal distribution in the interval (a,b).

From my point of view, the function consists of two draws:

First draw: a probability weighting function with probabilities p and (1-p).

Second draw: a draw from a truncated normal distribution in the interval (a,b).

f.e. `constant = 10; p = 0,3; 1-p = 0,7, a=5, b=15`

My idea was:

`r = random.choices([constant,random.normal()], weights=(0.3, 0.7))`

However, it does not seem to work and I don't know how to include the interval (a,b).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is on-target, but you're not tackling the normal distribution correctly.  First, if you're using `import random` your choices are `random.gauss(mu, sigma)` or `random.normalvariate(mu, sigma)`. There's no `normal()` function.  Second, the normal distribution has an infinite range. You can specify `mu`, the center of the distribution, and `sigma`, a measure of the spread such that ~95% of the results will fall in the range `mu ± 2*sigma`.  If you truly need to restrict the range, you'll need to write your own function with a loop to reject values outside the range limits and try again.

Here's a working example which shows your idea:

```python
import random

constant = -42
mu = 10
sigma = 2
for _ in range(10):
    r = random.choices((constant,random.gauss(mu, sigma)), weights=(0.3, 0.7))
    print(r)
```

With those values of `mu` and `sigma`, outcomes outside the range [5, 15] will be rare but can definitely still occur.

This produces outcomes such as:

```text
[7.674159248587632]
[-42]
[7.818652194185853]
[-42]
[7.418414458386396]
[11.855000252151326]
[12.398753049340957]
[9.663097201849096]
[-42]
[10.385663464672415]
```

If you don't like the brackets, `print(r[0])`.